# How can I force display-buffer to use one specific frame?

Tags: frames, display-buffer-alist

My daily workflow uses multiple frames, and I have a frame that I want to dedicate to ERC buffers.  I've used `set-frame-parameter` to give the frame the name `*ERC*`.

I want `display-buffer` to always display ERC buffers (identified by the regex `` \`# ``) in this frame named `*ERC*`.

I've tried the following:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
     '("\\`#"
       nil
       (inhibit-switch-frame)
       (reusable-frames . "*ERC*")))
```

But buffers still appear all over the place.  I've also tried replacing `*ERC*` with `\\*ERC\\*`.  Help?

Comment: I have answered this topic in a related thread entitled "**How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame**"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  Because I update the answer from time to time with various improvements, I will not be posting a duplicate answer in emacs.stackexchange.com  It works for both non-file-visiting buffers and file-visiting buffers.  The answer utilizes a couple of core functions written by Drew Adams -- i.e., `get-frame-name` and `get-a-frame`.

Comment: The first element should be a string, not a symbol, i.e. `"\\\`#"`.

Comment: It doesn't look like Stefan will be posting his comment as an answer. If you feel it provides the answer then please post the code as an answer. (You can accept your own answer.)

Comment: I made the change that Stefan recommended, but unfortunately that didn't make the buffers appear in the named frame. After spending some time today looking at this again, I'm getting the sense that custom display action functions must be a part of the solution, if not the whole thing. If I write one up I'll post it (in the meantime i just stopped using ERC)